# Adding event to calendar not respecting times

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-calendar

I'm trying to add a calendar event, however the start and end times are being ignored and instead it's just setting both to the next half hour from now. For example, right now it's 3:51pm so it's setting the start/end times to 4:00pm.

Here is the code for adding the event to the calendar:

```
public static void AddToCalendar (DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string title, 
            string description = null, string location = null) {
            var startDateTicks = DateTime.Now.AddHours (3).ConvertToUnixTimestampMillis ();
            var endDateTicks = DateTime.Now.AddDays (2).AddHours(2).ConvertToUnixTimestampMillis ();

            var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionInsert);
            intent.SetData (CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri);
            //intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, startDateTicks);
            //intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, endDateTicks);
            intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.ExtraEventBeginTime, startDateTicks);
            intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.ExtraEventEndTime, endDateTicks);
            intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.EventsColumns.Title, title);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (description))
                intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.EventsColumns.Description, description);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (location))
                intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.EventsColumns.EventLocation, location);
            ApplicationContext.Activity.StartActivity (intent);
        }
```

And here is the extension method for converting the dates to milliseconds:

```
public static double ConvertToUnixTimestampMillis (this DateTime date) {
            var epoch = new DateTime (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return (long)(date.ToUniversalTime () - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```

Below is the calendar event.

[image]

I tried setting both Dtstart / Dtend, and beginTime and endTime. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calendar is expecting milliseconds since epoch so you should use something like this to get the correct value:

```
long GetDateTimeMS (int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance (Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);

    c.Set (Calendar.DayOfMonth, day);
    c.Set (Calendar.HourOfDay, hr);
    c.Set (Calendar.Minute, min);
    c.Set (Calendar.Month, month);
    c.Set (Calendar.Year, yr);

    return c.TimeInMillis;
}
```

And call it in your code like this:

```
intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.ExtraEventBeginTime, DateTime.Now.AddHours(3));
intent.PutExtra (CalendarContract.ExtraEventEndTime, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).AddHours(2));
```